# How to get the output response from a state space equation?

Tags: matlab, matrix, state-space

For a state space equation in which matrix `A` is dependent on variable `t`(time), how can I get the step or output response?

This is the code, which doesn't work:

```
A = [sin(t) 0;0 cos(t)];
B = [0.5; 0.0];
C = [1 0; 0 1];
G = ss(A,B,C,[]);
step(G,t)
x0 = [-1;0;2];
initial(G,x0)
```

Here are error message:

> Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
>   consistent.
>
> Error in Response (line 11) A = [sin(t) 0;0 cos(t)];

Comment: How does your code not work? Error messages, unexpected behavior, crash, freeze, locusts etc.?

Comment: Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated
are not consistent.

Error in Response 
A = [sin(t) 0;0 cos(t)];

Comment: what is `t` ? the problem lies there probably

Comment: t is time, which is to say matrix  A changes with time.

Comment: The `ss` function generates an `LTI` system - that is, linear, time-**in**variant systems.  The `Control Toolbox` cannot be used to create or simulate time varying systems.  You should use `Simulink`, which is designed to model non-linear, time varying systems.

Comment: You could do this with [ode45](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html).  You'd need to use the technique shown in the section `ODE With Time Dependent Terms` to incorporate the input `u` to your system.  And the result would be your state-vector, which you would then have to multiple by your `C` matrix to get your required output.  But as per my previous comment, `Simulink` would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed already, you can only use the `ss` function to generate LTI systems, but you can discretise your model analytically using methods like forward Euler, backwards Euler, Tustin etc. and simulate your model using a `for` loop.

For your example, you could run something like this:

- consider a sampling period `h = 0.01` (or lower if the dynamics are not captured properly);
- select `N` as the number of steps for the simulation (100, 1000 etc.);
- declare the time instants vector `t = (0:N-1)*h`;
- create a `for` loop which computes the system states and outputs, here using the forward Euler method (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method):

  ```
  % A = [sin(t) 0;0 cos(t)]; 
  B = [0.5; 0.0];
  C = [1 0; 0 1];
  D = [0; 0];
  x0 = [-1;1];  % the initial state must have two elements as this is a second-order system
  u = 0;  % constant zero input, but can be modified
  N = 1000;
  h = 0.01;
  t = (0:N-1)*h;
  x_vec = [];
  y_vec = [];
  xk = x0;
  yk = [0;0];
  for k=1:N
      Ad = eye(2)+h*[sin(t(k)) 0; 0 cos(t(k))];
      Bd = h*B; % C and D remain the same
      yk = C*xk + D*u;
      xk = Ad*xk + Bd*u;
      x_vec = [x_vec, xk]; % keep results in memory
      y_vec = [y_vec, yk];
  end

  % Plot output response
  plot(t,y_vec);
  ```